# Присвоение переменной элементу двумерного массива c#

Tags: c#, массивы

Нужно двумерному массиву, одному из его элементов, присвоить переменную C и вычислить сумму элементов меньших С.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[,] d2array = new double[,]
        {
            {14.5, 16.7, 9.2, 6.5 },
            
    };
```

Comment: `одному из его элементов, присвоить переменную C` одному из элементов двумерного массива или одному из элементов вложенного одномерного?

Comment: можно пример `массив-результат`?

Comment: одному из элементов двумерного массива

Comment: ну переменная C которая представляет допустим второй индекс массива d2array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{
    double[,] d2array = new double[,]
    {
        {14.5, 16.7, 9.2, 6.5 },
        {4, 4, 7, 11 },
        {25, 35.6, 1, -1 },
    };
    
    var c = 2;      
    double sum = 0;
    
    for (int col = 0; col < d2array.GetLength(1); col++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < c; row++)
        {
            sum += d2array[row,col];
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```